# Prove that $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

> Prove that the expression $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0\; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

My try:: Using Interval method::

$\bullet \; $If $x\leq 0$, Then $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0$

$\bullet \; $If $0<x\leq 1$, Then $x^{12}+x^4.(1-x^5)+(1-x)>0$

$\bullet \; $If $x>1$, Then $x^9.(x^3-1)+x(x^3-1)+1>0$

So the expression $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0\; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

My question is How can I solve Using $A.M\geq G.M$ method. or How can I complete the

square so that the expression is $>0$

Thanks

Comment: Your solution is great, why look for more?

Comment: Something else you can do is possibly $$x^9(x^3-1)+x(x^3-1)+1=x(x^3-1)(x^8+1)+1.$$This doesn't apply AM-GM, but you might find it useful since now all you have to do is really think about the $x(x^3-1)$.

Comment: One way to complete the polynomial as a sum of squares is to use computer software like Sage, http://ask.sagemath.org/question/2517/polynomials-as-a-sum-of-squares

Using this method, your polynomial is a product of the following terms:

x^2 + 1.95290385397*x + 1.083986257,
x^2 + 1.27969985857*x + 1.08525732014,
x^2 + 0.75775637734*x + 1.21948813932,
x^2 - 0.661972813924*x + 1.02442791168,
x^2 - 1.32870898709*x + 0.643542165713,
x^2 - 1.99967828887*x + 1.05732258414

I'm not sure if this is what you want as there is no closed form expressions for the roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{4}x^{12}+x^6&\ge |x^9|\ge x^9\\
\frac{3}{4}x^{12}+\frac13&\ge x^6\\
x^4+\frac14&\ge x^2\\
x^2+\frac14&\ge |x|\ge x
\end{aligned}$$
Add them all up, you get that 
$$x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1\ge \frac16.$$

---

Another proof:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{x^{12}+x^{12}+x^{12}+1}4&\ge \sqrt[4]{x^{36}}\ge x^9\\
\frac{x^4+1+1+1}{4}&\ge \sqrt[4]{x^4}\ge x.
\end{aligned}$$
The inequality follows.